# Passing Regex string in JSON body

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, http, postman

I am trying to send regex string in JSON body of my http request like this

```
{
  "pattern":"\b\d{8}\b"
}
```

But I get a 400 response from the server

```
Unexpected token d in JSON at position xxx
```

If I try to escape the "\" in the JSON body like

```
{
  "pattern":"\b\\d{8}\b"
}
```

The server doesn't throw any error but the request body received in the server end is incorrect

```
Expectation: 
{
  "pattern":"\b\d{8}\b"
}

Result:
{
  "pattern":"\b\\d{8}\b"
}
```

Any inputs or references will be helpful.

Thanks,

Comment: `{"pattern":"/\\b\\d{8}\\b/"}` might work? Note that the back slashes are escaped, and I've added forward slashes to denote that it's an actual RegExp

Comment: It did not work, in this case even the body which I received on the server end was `{"pattern":"/\\b\\d{8}\\b/"}` and not `{"pattern":"\b\d{8}\b"}`

Comment: You probably need to fix it at the source, the server, because the output isn't valid JSON. This `{"pattern":"\\b\\d{8}\\b"}` is.

Answer (score 0):

Did you trying sending as string
First in requesting side

```
JSON.stringify({ "pattern":"\b\\d{8}\b" })
```

in controller side

```
public class myregex
{
    public string pattern{ get; set; }
}
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<myregex>(json)
```